# I want to put a bitmap inside imageview keeping aspect ratio

Tags: android, bitmap, android-imageview

This is my xml code:

```
        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ColImgPath"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@drawable/border"/>
```

and this my java code, that it is inside listview:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ColImgPath);
        imageView.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    try {
            Bitmap bmp = ((Bitmap) MyArrList.get(position).get("ImageThumBitmap"));
            int bmpx = bmp.getWidth();
            int bmpy = bmp.getHeight();

            Log.i("INFO","X: "+bmpx+" Y: "+bmpy);

            Bitmap photobitmap1 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, bmpx/2,bmpy/2, true);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(photobitmap1);
            //imageView.setImageBitmap((Bitmap) MyArrList.get(position).get("ImageThumBitmap"));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // When Error
            imageView.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_report_image);
        }
```

The problem is that I want to put the bitmap resized into bitmap but the imageview always appears squared.
The size of the bitmap is: `X: 4160 Y: 3120` and the screen size is : `WIDTH= 1080 HEIGHT= 1776`

I want to put the width fill parent and resize the height keeping the aspect ratio. I tried some xml alternatives like `ScaleType.

Someone knows the way to put correctly the bitmap?

Answer (score 0):

Does fitXy not work for the scale type?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Answer (score 0):

It's an `ImageView` so you need to use `android:src="@drawable/border"` instead of `android:background`. Also try `android:scaleType="fitXY"` or `cropCenter`.

Comment: I load the imageview with an image from my server. This works fine, the border is only for know why the photo is not shown completely in the imageview

Answer (score 0):

There are different Scale Type Available in Android ImageView

CENTER_INSIDE -  used to set Bitmap with keeping bitmap original aspect ratio.

CENTER_CROP   -  used to set Bitmap in imageview to cover imageview without broken aspect Ratio , rather bitmap set from negative x , y value  to cover imageview area.

FIT_XY    -  used to set whole bitmap into available ImageView  height and width means bitmap takes Imageviews Aspect Ratio.

```
                              OR
```

if you want to resize bitmap then take height or width which you want to set  and take ratio of height / width if take width or take width/ height if you have next height  and multiply repetitive width and height to this ratio .It will change height and width of bitmap but keep Aspect Ratio of original Bitmap .